# stored-proc-outbound-gateway fetch size and batch update

Tags: spring-integration, c3p0, spring-jdbc

I have been using stored-proc-outbound-gateway for both update and select as the database layer only allows stored procedures to my application.
I would like to set jdbc fetch size to a higher number as currently it is taking very long to read records, but i don’t see a way to do that, How can i achieve this in SI configuration?

```
   <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway 
                id="dataLoad"
                data-source="someDataSource"
                request-channel="triggerChannel" 
                reply-channel="DataChannel"
                stored-procedure-name="${inbound.sp.name}"
                ignore-column-meta-data="true">             
                <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition....                                                                                              
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

On related topic, I would also like to know if there is a possibility to achieve batch update for performance reasons.

I am using C3P0 data-source, so not sure if there anything in the configuration there that can help.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean this `Statement.setFetchSize` ? But its default is `0`. From its JavaDocs: `* If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored.
     * The default value is zero.` Anyway I'm not sure that those `Statement`'s options are affect to the `CallableStatement`...

Comment: Fetch size, more details for oracle - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm I have used setFathcSize very successfully in raw jdbc and it dramatically improves performance of large data reads

Comment: Also i am not sure at what point the row mapper is employed, is it used as the data is read from database or after reading all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fetch size, more details for oracle - docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm I have used setFathcSize very successfully in raw jdbc and it dramatically improves performance of large data reads

Well, that option isn't available for the `SimpleJdbcCall` used internally by the `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`, but I see that the default `10 rows` option can be configured for the `Datasource`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/basic.htm. See `defaultRowPrefetch`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, Statement.setFetchSize(size) is available in jdbc and supported by oracle driver, what i have experienced in the past. I am using C3P0 data-source, will explore if i can configure it at that level.

Comment: C3P0 does support connection properties and works great <prop key="defaultRowPrefetch">1000</prop>